# PHP code on orbited comet server

Tags: php, comet, orbited

Where can I find the PHP sample code for orbited comet server v0.7?

I think that I have to build another server together with orbited server in order to support the comet function. Am I right? If so, how can I build up that server?

Answer (score 2):

Use hookbox: http://github.com/mcarter/hookbox